# Reading bits in 5-bits chunk in "Memory Aligned" way

Tags: c, embedded

For example, I am trying to read 15 bits from Starting address lets say "11". By definition of memory aligned (15 % 5 == 0). How to read or write these bits in terms (Memory Aligned Access) but the location of bits should also be in such a way that only 1 byte should be read to read a chunk of 5 bits. My thought would be that memory aligned reading should be in the following way.

```
MSB x  x  x  x  x  x  LSB   : Byte read
 0  0  0  15 14 13 12 11    : 0  
 0  0  0  20 19 18 17 16    : 1
 0  0  0  25 24 23 22 21    : 2
Most-significant three bits are 0-padded in all bytes.
```

Please share your thoughts and also help me writing a C code to read bits in chunk of 5 bits? Thanks

Comment: What is startin address? In bytes or bits? What is byte read? Explain

Comment: I am actually working on Modbus. Read Coils (bits). The starting address is a 2 byte parameter with the range from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. "Byte read" I have used as a indexing of buffer array from where I have to read these bits. 0 represent the first byte, 1 represent the 2nd byte and so on.

Comment: first byte of what? that row? something else? BE PRECISE

Comment: buffer array is "uint8_t[5U]" i.e. an array of 5 entities and every index is 1 byte value. I am reading bits from this buffer.

Comment: "the location of bits should also be in such a way that only 1 byte should be read to read a chunk of 5 bits" Thats not going to happen unless you use padding bits.

Comment: Can you point us to the Modbus documentation related to what you ask?

Comment: https://www.modbus.org/specs.php "Modbus Protocol Specification". Function Code 0x01 "Read Coils" that defines object size of 1-bit read. But object size can be any value 5-bit read, 7-bit at once.

Comment: @lulle. This is why I have assumed above diagram in which every 5-bitchunk I have assumed to be starting the least significant bit position of the respective byte with higher bits zero padded.  I need help in writing generic C code for this x-bits chunk reading and writing.

Comment: You have confused the issue by using the term "memory aligned" in a sense it is not normally used.  Memory alignment refers to bytes of words and their addresses; for example the MSB of a aligned 16 bit word in a big-endian device would be at an even address.  Here it is not at all clear what you mean. I am guessing you mean "packed" rather than aligned; but without details of the packing (left/right justified, byte order etc.) it is not possible to advise.  Specify the device or link/duplicate the documentation for the data source in question because your description is ambiguous.

Comment: You cannot make "assumptions" and we cannot guess.  You/we need specification; this is not it

Comment: What does "15%5" seek (and fail) to clarify? You mention later in a comment a uint8_t array of 5. That information should be in the question. You clearly have some existing code related to this; that should probably be in the question too. You only mention three bytes in the question, but you have 5. Is that then 8 packed 5 bit words or some other structure/alignment?

Comment: Wasim, please [edit] your question with new information. Down here in the comments it's too hard to find.